# Show two array values inside one foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm retrieving the JSON array from my DB and my array is:

```
{"Position":["first","second","third","fourth"],"Color":["Red",Blue,Pink,Teal]}
```

I want to show them in table inside a foreach loop

```xml
@foreach ($orderProduct->column as $item)
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ $item['Position'] }}</th>
      <th>{{ $item['Color'] }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
@endforeach
```

I want the output to be like this

```xml
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>first</th>
    <th>Red</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>second</th>
    <th>Blue</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>third</th>
    <th>Pink</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I want the output to be like this

`<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>  first </th>
        <th> Red </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>  second </th>
        <th> Blue </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
 <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>  third </th>
        <th> Pink </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>`

@Peppermintology

Comment: Are you sure your array is a PHP array? It looks like you have a JSON array there.

Comment: Yes, that's a Json array that I'm trying to render from Database column @OluwafemiSule

Comment: I updated my original question and included the output, maybe it looks clearer over there. As per my foreach loop, it should output like that, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($orderProduct->column['Position']); $i++)
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ $orderProduct->column['Position'][$i] }}</th>
      <th>{{ $orderProduct->column['Color'][$i] }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

```xml
@foreach (array_combine($orderProduct['Position'], $orderProduct['Color']) as $position => $color)
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ $position }}</th>
      <th>{{ $color }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried your code, it works but it only outputs 2 rows (loops only once) when it should output 4. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using Laravel, I would suggest to make use of the `Collection`'s `zip` method that "*merges together the values of the given array with the values of the original collection at their corresponding index*" ([Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-zip))

You would use it like this:

```php
$newArray = collect($array['Position'])->zip($array['Color']);

@foreach($newArray as [$position, $color])
  {{ $position }}
  {{ $color }}
@endforeach
```